# Using the ST_Disjoint() Function gives unexpected result

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geospatial, spatial, spatial-query

I am fiddeling around with this dataset http://s3.cleverelephant.ca/postgis-workshop-2020.zip. It is used in this workshop http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html.

I want to identify all the features, that do not have a subway station. I thought this spatial join is rather straight forward

```
SELECT
  census.boroname,
  COUNT(census.boroname)
FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
    JOIN nyc_subway_stations AS subway
        ON ST_Disjoint(census.geom, subway.geom)
GROUP BY census.boroname;
```

However, the result set is waaaaay to large.

```
"Brooklyn"  4753693
"Manhattan" 1893156
"Queens"    7244123
"Staten Island" 2473146
"The Bronx" 2683246
```

When I run a test

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nyc_census_blocks;
```

I get `38794` as a result. So there are way less features in `nyc_census_blocks` than I have in the result-set from the spatial join.

Why is that? Where is the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with `ST_Disjoint` you're getting for every record of `nyc_census_block` the total number of stations that are disjoint with `nyc_subway_stations`, which means in case of no intersection **all records** of `nyc_subway_stations` (491). That's why you're getting such a high count.

Alternatively you can count how many subways and census blocks do intersect, e.g. in a CTE or subquery, and in another query count how many of them return `0`:

```
WITH j AS (
 SELECT 
   gid,census.boroname,
  (SELECT count(*) 
   FROM nyc_subway_stations subway
   WHERE ST_Intersects(subway.geom,census.geom)) AS qt
 FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
)
SELECT boroname,count(*)
FROM j WHERE qt = 0
GROUP BY boroname;

   boroname    | count 
---------------+-------
 Brooklyn      |  9517
 Manhattan     |  3724
 Queens        | 14667
 Staten Island |  5016
 The Bronx     |  5396
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Hm... Maybe that explains the high count, however: Why does it return all the NYC Census Blocks geomtries? It then should at least return all the geometries, that are disjoint with the subway stations?!

Comment: @Stophface does it? This query does not return any geometry, only their `boroname`. There are multiple geometries with the same `boroname`, so this query in the end groups by geometries by `boroname`s that had zero stations. See `SELECT DISTINCT boroname FROM nyc_census_blocks;`

Comment: Sorry, I was speaking about mine, slighlty edited query from my Q. When I run this `SELECT census.boroname, census.geom
FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
JOIN nyc_subway_stations AS subway 
ON ST_Disjoint(subway.geom, census.geom)
GROUP BY census.boroname, census.geom;` I get a lot of geometries.... I expect only a few, namely the ones that do not have a subway station.

Comment: @Stophface sure, now it does, as you declared it in your `SELECT` statement.. in my query and in the OP it wasn't.  Of course you're now getting more results, as the geometries inside of `nyc_census_blocks` are distinct and a group by involving geom will return multiple rows even when the `boroname` is identical.

Comment: @Stophface I cannot test it right now, but maybe it helps: `WITH j AS (
 SELECT 
   gid,census.boroname,census.geom,
  (SELECT count(*) 
   FROM nyc_subway_stations subway
   WHERE ST_Intersects(subway.geom,census.geom)) AS qt
 FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
)
SELECT gid,boroname,geom
FROM j WHERE qt = 0;`

Comment: Okay, now I am completly confused... How would I select all the geometries from nyc_census_blocks that do not have a subway station, using `ST_Disjoint()`

Comment: @Stophface I'll have to download the data again to test it (pretty hard to test spatial sql without seeing the data :D). Just out of curiosity: why do you explicitly need to use `ST_Disjoint`?

Comment: Haha yes it is indeed ;)
Because I want to understand all the variations of Spatial Joins there are :)

Comment: @Stophface I see. Well, imho a disjoint here only make things more complicated: in the last query you posted, you sort of create a result set for every possible disjoint of both tables, meaning that if a block has no intersection with any station it will appear 491 times in your result set. There is certainly a way to make this query work with `ST_Disjoint`, but solely relying on it in a spatial join is probably not the best choice.

Comment: @Stophface btw: do you know in which SRS these shapefiles are encoded? I don't have a GIS here ..

Comment: Yes, they are in SRID 26918

Comment: @Stophface I guess you could collect all subway geometries to make the spatial join cost less`SELECT
  census.boroname,
  census.geom
FROM nyc_census_blocks AS census
JOIN (SELECT ST_Collect(geom) AS geom 
   FROM nyc_subway_stations) j
   ON ST_Disjoint(census.geom, j.geom);` but it would be by many orders of magnitude slower than using `ST_Intersect`. As I mentioned in my previous post, a spatial join relying exclusively in a disjoint isn't easy and almost always a less efficient choice. I hope it is clearer now .. cheers and happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and explanation!